# Is $(g \circ f)^{-1} (x)$ equal to $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x)$ or not?

Tags: functions

Is $(g \circ f)^{-1} (x)$ equal to $(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x)$ or not?

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: Have you tried some simple examples?

Comment: Think they would both have to be invertible.

Comment: Try $f(x)=2x, g(x)= 2x$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1})(x)$?

Comment: You have asked if, in general, the inverse of the composition of two functions can equal the composition of those same two functions. This is obviously not possible. Perhaps you've made a typo?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes. It is what you have written. You have solved my question.

Comment: @mathtastic: If $f(x)=g(x) = x$ it is possible. :-)

Comment: I edited the question to reflect @dj1's comment above.

Comment: @ copper.hat - Notice I specifically said 'in general.' I wrote my comment that way to specifically address the rare instances where his proposition might me true. Had he specified that f(x)=g(x) then yes, that would be the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}$(At least if $f$ and $g$ are invertible.) In general in a group we have $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Applying this to $(\langle f,g\rangle,\circ)$ yields $(g\circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.
One can also verify directly that $(g\circ f)\circ(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})=\id=(f^{-1}\circ g^{-1})\circ(g\circ f)$.